# Android software corrupting again and again

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

i'm using micromax unite 2 mobile for about 1.5 year. After just more than 1 year of its usage its software got corrupt. As the warranty was over so i had to spend money to get it repaired from micromax care. But then after 1 month its soffware again got corrupt. So again had to spend money to get it repaired. Then again after 20 days its software was corrupted. Please tell me why my mobile's software is corrupting again and again?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "its software got corrupt"? What were the symptoms?

Comment: Dan- its software got corrupt means mobile stuck on logo screen, stuck in boot loop. The time when we need to flash a new ROM.

Answer (score 1):

I am also a unite 2 user and i had faced this problem. However i repaired it myself. May be the problem is with your ROM. Micromax customer care service is of worst level so leave them. Here is a fixe.

- **Flash a new stock ROM. Download ROM And installation guide from [here](http://www.droidgyan.com/recovery-flashable-stock-rom/)**

Flash ROM with the help of SP flash tool and format your device before flashing(its easy)

Comment: Subhnish the link you gave me would work if android 4.4 is installed. But on my phone android 5.0 is installed so could you give me guide on how to get kitkat from lollipop and are u sure the ROM is the main problem of software corrupting and again.

Comment: Hi yadwinder, Your problem is "software corrupting" which means its related to software., and i can say with confidence that flashing ROM is the best option right now. However you can find any type of ROM on google, but here i am giving a link of Lollipop ROM.  "http://www.droidgyan.com/update-lollipop/".

Answer (score 0):

As your warranty is over, you may push custom recovery and flash a custom or stock room in your unite 2. You can get all the resources @forum.xdadevelopers.com. Trust me I have flashed my phone and bricked it hundreds of time experimenting and didn't spend a rupee on it